# Typescript 2.0 pass Datetime parameter to WebApi controller

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I've a angular 2 application with Typescript 2.0 and I need to pass a datetime parameter to my web api controller from typescript.

but it doesn't work since it passes the default date to the controller

Here is my angular controller code

```
   this.profileService
            .getAvailableConsultant(this.ignoreList,currentUser.providerId,new Date(),1)
            .subscribe(result => {


}));
```

And my angular service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { APP_CONFIG, IAppConfig } from '../app.config';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {
    apiURL: string;

    constructor(public http: Http, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig) {
        this.apiURL = config.apiEndpoint;
    }

    getAvailableConsultant(ignoreList: string, providerId: number, currDate: Date, mode: number) {
        var url: string = this.apiURL + "UserProfile/GetAvailableConsultant?" +
            "ignoreList=" + ignoreList +
            "&providerId=" + providerId +
            "&currdate=" + currDate +
            "&mode=" + mode
            ;
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
}
```

This is the Web Api Controller Code

```
 [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetAvailableConsultant")]
        public UserProfileDto GetAvailableConsultant(string ignoreList, int providerId,DateTime currdate,int mode)
        {
            return _profileService.GetAvailableConsultant(ignoreList,providerId, currdate,mode);
        }
```

It passes

> 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

as currDate to the controller

Comment: What doesn't work? Where's the error? In the Web Api action? Is the `currdate` not being correctly parsed?

Comment: yes it passes date as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: I see. Try this. In your Angular Service use: `"&currdate=" + currDate.toISOString() + ...` See if that makes a difference?

Comment: Date is a notoriously difficult data type for serialization/deserialization across languages. Hope `.toISOString()` helps, but if not, use Fiddler to intercept the incoming call to your server and make sure that the date field is being serialized in a format that your controller can deserialize.

Comment: @ArashMotamedi it worked but the problem is it shows a wrong time

Comment: What date is being parsed? My guess is that it's a timezone issue now. In your action, change `DateTime` to `DateTimeOffset` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: when I use `currDate.toLocaleString() ` it works

Answer (score 0):

This will help you. It will support all TS

Pass date like this **currDate.toISOString()**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { APP_CONFIG, IAppConfig } from '../app.config';

@Injectable()
export class ProfileService {
    apiURL: string;

    constructor(public http: Http, @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: IAppConfig) {
        this.apiURL = config.apiEndpoint;
    }

    getAvailableConsultant(ignoreList: string, providerId: number, currDate: Date, mode: number) {
        var url: string = this.apiURL + "UserProfile/GetAvailableConsultant?" +
            "ignoreList=" + ignoreList +
            "&providerId=" + providerId +
            "&currdate=" + currDate.toISOString() +
            "&mode=" + mode
            ;
        return this.http.get(url);
    }
}
```